# AWS CDK Python Create App Load Balancer Listner with default action

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to move over from Cloudformation to CDK and have been struggling here.
I'm trying to create a ELB listner and add a default action to it. Port 80 Listner with default action to redirect to 443.  It seems like this should be easy but I can't see any way to hook in to the default actions for a listner. Some sources say default_action is a prop of the Listner class but I can't seem to find how to use it on instantiation. Others say to use .add_action as in this example:

```
    listener80.add_action('DefaultAction',
        elbv2.ListenerAction.fixed_response(200,
            content_type=elbv2.ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN,
            message_body="OK"
            ))
```

However i keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2' has no attribute 'ContentType'
```

Even though that example is straight out of AWS docs...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling like i was here is the way to declare it on instantiation:

```
 listener80 = lb.add_listener(
            "listener80",
            port=80,
            default_action=elbv2.ListenerAction.redirect(host="#{host}", path="/#{path}", permanent=True, port="443", protocol="HTTPS", query="#{query}")
        )
```

or to add it with add action:

```
listener80.add_action('DefaultAction', action=elbv2.ListenerAction.redirect(host="#{host}", path="/#{path}", permanent=True, port="443", protocol="HTTPS", query="#{query}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and until now I didn't find any information about the new position of the enum ContentType in cdk v2, alternatively, according to the definition of the interface FixedResponseOptions :

```
export interface FixedResponseOptions {
/**
 * Content Type of the response
 *
 * Valid Values: text/plain | text/css | text/html | application/javascript | application/json
 *
 * @default - Automatically determined
 */
readonly contentType?: string;
/**
 * The response body
 *
 * @default - No body
 */
readonly messageBody?: string;}
```

I just put a string value instead, for example 'text/plain'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).